# Looking for a CSS usage checker

Tags: web-development, css

I've got a legacy web app with dozens of stylesheets that are variously included in hundreds of pages. The styles are bloated and it's a little dangerous to make changes because it's hard to predict how a change might affect the site globally.

So I'd like a tool that could scan all the stylesheets and all the pages and identify things like:

- styles that aren't used anywhere
- styles that are defined in multiple places
- styles with multiple selectors defining the same effect